# Alter table add column if not exists in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to make an alter table via migration on a node:14 server with umzug.

The code is :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'user'
AND table_schema = 'table_schema'
AND column_name = 'username3') THEN

ALTER TABLE 'table_schema'.'user' ADD COLUMN username3' varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
END IF
```

but if I run this "without a stored procedure", I get this error

> Error SQL [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that > corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT
> EXISTS(
> SELECT *
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> WHERE table_name ' at line 2

With the stored procedure, it runs without error.

Any suggestion about that?

Comment: What is the problem with using a stored procedure?

Comment: is it the best way to solve the problem? use a stored procedure create by a migration ? that's all

Comment: You can always drop the stored procedure after, or as a last step, in your migration.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of managing schema changes with migrations that you know what tables and columns exist, given the schema version? You should not need any `IF EXISTS` logic.

Comment: you are right @BillKarwin, but in my case I have to create migration that check existing db (from production), so I must check to aviod errros

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add a `USE <dbname>` before your `IF EXISTS` code.

The stored procedure runs under a context which provides the database name which may not be available when you run independently.

Comment: Your statement is not true. Sorry I cannot find the document where it says, but a stored procedure will run in the database where it is defined, no need for `USE...`

Comment: Because `use` is a [mysql Client Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), you cannot use it in a stored procedure, and structures like `BEGIN....END` need to be run in a stored procedure (or function).

Comment: @Luuk That's exactly what I am saying. SP knows what DB to run under by definition. isolated queries do not. Therefore I recommended added USE in isolated query run. I did not say add them to SP.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
     IF NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * 
     FROM   sys.columns 
     WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'user') 
     AND name = 'username3'
     )
      BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE user ADD  username3 varchar(50) NOT NULL 
      DEFAULT ;
      END
```

Comment: [OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is MSSQL, The question is about MySQL

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html says:

> This section describes the syntax for the `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events.

The other compound statements mentioned by this sentence include `IF ... THEN ... END IF`. This means you can't use these statements as direct SQL. They must be inside a `BEGIN ... END` block, and that must be in a stored program. This is the reason you get a syntax error as soon as you use the token `IF` in an SQL query directly, but you don't get the error if you use it in a stored procedure.

But MySQL also has an [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) you can use for scalar expressions. With this, you can test a condition and return one or the other expression. Then you can assign the result to a string variable, and run that as a new dynamic SQL statement. The "else" part of this expression is `DO TRUE` which is a statement that will serve as a no-op.

```
SET @query = IF(
    NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE table_name = 'user'
      AND table_schema = 'table_schema'
      AND column_name = 'username3'
    ),
    'ALTER TABLE `table_schema`.`user` ADD COLUMN username3 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''''',
    'DO TRUE'
  );
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Also notice I replaced the quotes in your ALTER TABLE statement. Use back-ticks as identifier delimiters. Use single-quotes as string delimiters. If you need to use literal single-quotes inside a string, use two single-quote characters for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Alter table user add username3 varchar(50) not null default '';

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column conditionally with a little script like this:

```
SET @nameSchema := 'mySchemaName';
SET @nameTable := 'myTableName';
SET @nameCol := 'myColName';
SET @colDef := 'varchar(10) NULL default \'test\'';

-- check if column already exists
SET @colExists := (
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`= @nameSchema
    AND `TABLE_NAME`= @nameTable
    AND `COLUMN_NAME`= @nameCol);

-- prepare the two different queries
SET @theQuery = IF (@colExists <= 0, 
    concat_ws(' ', 'ALTER TABLE',  concat(@nameSchema, '.',  @nameTable), 'ADD COLUMN' , @nameCol, @colDef),
    concat_ws(' ', 'SELECT \'Warning: Column',  @nameCol, 'already exists!\' AS info'));
SELECT @theQuery;  
 
PREPARE stmt from @theQuery;
EXECUTE stmt;
```